# How to use exec statement in a sourced file in Tcl

Tags: module, tcl

I am trying to use the following command in a file sourced by another one but the variable doesn't seem to be usefull. The PYTHONPATH var is filled by `lib//site-packages` and not `lib/python2.7/site-packages`

my_path:

```
set pyver      [ exec python -c {import sys;print 'python%d.%d'%(sys.version_info[0],sys.version_info[1])} ]enter code here
array set paths {
PATH               bin
PYTHONPATH         lib/$pyver/site-packages
}
```

main:

```
#%Module1.0########################################
##
##  Modulefile for texworks
#
source my_path
foreach p [array names paths] {
prepend-path $p $paths($p)
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual code you use? The braces should prevent variable substitution and give you the value `lib/$pyver/site-packages`. Have you verified what the value of `pyver` is?

Comment: @Hoodiecrow How can I make `$pyver` to be substitute by its value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initialize the array `paths` like this:

```
array set paths {
    PATH               bin
    PYTHONPATH         lib/$pyver/site-packages
}
```

the braces around the member initializations prevent variable substitution of the variable `pyver`. To allow the variable to be substituted, you need to either replace the braces by double quotes (which is somewhat poor style) or write this as

```
array set paths [list \
    PATH               bin \
    PYTHONPATH         lib/$pyver/site-packages \
]
```

or (setting each member individually)

```
set paths(PATH)       bin
set paths(PYTHONPATH) lib/$pyver/site-packages
```

or (forcing substitution)

```
array set paths [subst {
    PATH               bin
    PYTHONPATH         lib/$pyver/site-packages
}]
```

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm)

Comment: I would strongly recommend doing them individually in this case.